# Replacing .xls or .xlsx with .txt

Tags: c#

I myself can do this with a bunch of string methods in many lines of code but was hoping there is some smarter way of doing this:

client enters a path like `"C:\someFolder\WhaEver.xlsx"` in the `app.config` file,
I want to have a string in my code that is the same value but with a `.txt` extension.
So I could use `.Replace(".xlsx",".txt" )`  but what if he has it as `".XLS"`  or `".XLSX"` , etc..? some variations on that...
So that's why I posted the question to see if there is better way of doing this?

Comment: [Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: ah, cool...yeah, then I can append my own .txt to it

Comment: [Path.ChangeExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.changeextension(v=vs.110).aspx) might be even better.

Comment: Yes that does it too! Glad I posted the question! Was gonna do it with bunch of String methods!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the path extension using `Path.ChangeExtension`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.changeextension(v=vs.110).aspx

```
 string file= @"C:\mydir\file.xls";

 string result = Path.ChangeExtension(file, ".txt");
```

The resulting string will have a .txt extension.